# Pentaho/Mondrian: how to set "dynamic roles" for logged user?

Tags: security, pentaho, mondrian, user-roles

I want to filter *sales data for Agent Dimension*. One Agent can log in Pentaho and see only his data and related sub-agent (hierarchy agent-sub agent is defined in a `closure table`). I can't do a Role for every Agent because the dimension is SCD type 2 (so the structure/relation between agent/sub-agent can vary in time).

*How I can obtain this particular filter/role schema access?*

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
[Here](https://github.com/gioma68/mondrian-dsp) you can find a sample code for my solution (ant project on Github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Dynamic Schema Processing. 
There are some resources on the web :

http://thejavatar.com/dynamic-schema-processor-modify-mondrian-schema-in-run-time/

Although it seems to use the Entreprise Edition, it should be interesting

Comment: Thanks, I've just finished to read the post. I will try It with Pentaho 5.4.0 CE.

Comment: If someone can be interested [here](https://github.com/gioma68/mondrian-dsp) can be found  my working example (ant project on Github) following how-to suggested by @bhericher ... thank again for you support

Comment: @giovanni Thanks for sharing. I don't remember, once you've configured your server and restarted it, if you then just modify the java code can you just redeploy it or must you restart the server again?

Comment: hi @bhericher, yes if modify the source java code for DSP and rebuild jar lib, you must first stop Pentaho, redeploy the jar in the Pentaho lib (overwriting, or removing the older) and restart pentaho.